# macOS - virtual memory limit (architectural or practical)?

Tags: macos, memory, virtual-memory

Is there a specific limit (configurable, hypothetical) to the amount of memory macOS can use?

I know there are several related factors, like addressable RAM, how virtual memory is used by the system, and the assumption that there is enough free disk space.

I couldn't find a single article that explained the maximum.

(Posted in superuser after reading discussions in meta, but feel free to edit or move this as needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there a specific limit (configurable, hypothetical) to the amount of memory macOS can use?

The amount of virtual memory is up to 18 exabytes of addressable space for 64-bit processes.

This assumes you have a sufficient amount of disk space available.

> **About the Virtual Memory System**
>
> Efficient memory management is an important aspect of writing high
>   performance code in both OS X and iOS. Minimizing memory usage not
>   only decreases your application’s memory footprint, it can also reduce
>   the amount of CPU time it consumes. In order to properly tune your
>   code though, you need to understand something about how the underlying
>   system manages memory.
>
> Both OS X and iOS include a fully-integrated virtual memory system
>   that you cannot turn off; it is always on. Both systems also provide
>   up to 4 gigabytes of addressable space per 32-bit process. In
>   addition, OS X provides approximately 18 exabytes of addressable space
>   for 64-bit processes. Even for computers that have 4 or more gigabytes
>   of RAM available, the system rarely dedicates this much RAM to a
>   single process.
>
> To give processes access to their entire 4 gigabyte or 18 exabyte
>   address space, OS X uses the hard disk to hold data that is not
>   currently in use. As memory gets full, sections of memory that are not
>   being used are written to disk to make room for data that is needed
>   now. The portion of the disk that stores the unused data is known as
>   the backing store because it provides the backup storage for main
>   memory.

Source [About the Virtual Memory System](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/AboutMemory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001880-BCICIHAB)